# Is bash in windows implemented differently from native bash, specifically for loops

Tags: bash, generator, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cpu-cache

I ran the following command on mac in an ad hoc fashion in mac store:

```
time for x in {1..5000000}; do if ! (($x % 10000)); then echo $x; fi done
```

to perform a very rudimentary benchmark. What this does is that it creates a list from 1 - 5000000, check if it's divisible by 10000, and print if it does. And `time` benchmark the time for the process to execute. I've been arriving at around 40 secs for macbook air, 32 for pros, all 8th gen intel processors. A particular pattern I noticed is that it freezes for a long time before printing out anything, presumably this is because it's creating a list from `1` to `5000000` and putting it in memory.

However, my friend who use windows reported faster times on gen 5 core m processor with Windows 10 native bash shell, on the order of 15 seconds. I suspect it's because windows `bash` treat `for x in {1..5000000}` as a generator. In this way the process never made into memory as everything would only needed to be stored in cache, achieving greater speed. Can anyone confirm that for loops for bash interpreter is the same/different across windows implementation and linux/mac implementations?

Comment: Compare the results in same hardware.

Comment: @Biswapriyo That's not possible, I don't own any hardware running windows.